# Selecting a value from android resource

Tags: java, android, arrays

In javascript, we can conditionally select a value from a object using a variable as,

```
var myObj = {"a": "Val1", "b": "Val2", "c": "Val3"};
var key = "a";
var val = myObj[key];
```

What is the similar method to select the value from a string resource file in android using variable string name?

We can select a string as `R.string.mystring` in android and from a java public class

```
public class myarray {
    public static final String test = "Test";    
    public myarray(){    
    }
}
```

as `String val = myarray.test;` but we wanted a method something similar to above javascript.

Comment: You can have an array of String.

Answer (score 2):

A translation of your javascript code is the following:

```
HashMap<String, String> myObj = new HashMap<String, String>();
myObj.put("a","Val1");
myObj.put("b","Val2");
myObj.put("c","Val3");
String key = "a";
String value = myObj.get(key);
```

Comment: How can we declare HashMap as public class?